# (Not Solved Again) How to root Gabb Wireless Z2?

Tags: adb, rooting, rom-flashing, gabb

(UPDATE: The accepted answer has since been patched. 12-16-2021)

I have a Gabb Wireless which is an Android that is programmed to be "dumb". By "dumb", I mean it only has core apps such as Settings, Phone, Messaging, etc. I like it because it is not additive to where I can't focus on my school.

It has some major drawbacks though. To keep kids from messing up the restrictions, they pretty much bricked the phone. I can't flash, ADB*, install apps**, or unlock the bootloader*** the way other sites say to do.

All I want to do is host a web server and customize the OS a bit. I have contacted the distributor and of course, they would not reveal anything.

Stars:

1. The original way to allow USB debugging/Developer mode is gone.
2. The store was removed and you can't install raw APKs.
3. When I boot into the Bootloader, the screen is blank with "=> FASTBOOT mode..." at the bottom.

Overall, I am disappointed with the extremes which the company took. I have gotten them to admit that the device *is* hackable. Of course, any device is hackable so I did not get much from that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a heads-up, due to [the cat-and-mouse situation with Gabb](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/installing-apps-on-a-gabb-phone-z2.4203577/post-85677153), I'm afraid any workarounds that are posted publicly from/to here will be patched by them again, though looks like [they have published a guide on Nov 4](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/installing-apps-on-a-gabb-phone-z2.4203577/post-85885697) (**please also read the rest of the thread since there's a mixed result, including a possibility of *bricking the phone***).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got half an answer for you.

I was able to get apps on my Gabb phone. What you do is get an ADB program like [this one](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/). Next, you want to extract the contents of the `platform-tools` file to a new folder in your (C:) drive called `adb`. Next, you are going to set up USB Debugging on your phone by going into your settings in your Gabb phone, Privacy, Permission manager, and search "autofill" and press on the one with developer options under it, turn on developer options at the top then look for USB Debugging and turn it on.

Now back on your computer open the Command prompt, take the charger, and plug one end into the computer and the other into your gabb phone. Get an APK file like [this one](https://m.apkpure.com/google-maps/com.google.android.apps.maps) and once it's done installing, go to your command prompt and type: `cd C:\adb` then enter. Next, type `adb install`, then insert your file then press Enter. Now the app has been installed and that's how you get apps, it's easy and it worked for me so, have fun getting apps on your Gabb Phone!

I don't have an answer for the rooting part though sorry.

Comment: Looks like they pushed up update that blocks the ability to access developer mode.

Comment: Maybe you could downgrade to a previous version of the phone before the update

Comment: when I try to enable USB debugging, it won't let me enter into the developer settings. They stripped the thing down pretty well. Maybe a new firmware update?